# How do I change my column sort to sort the entire sheet not just a column?

Tags: excel, sorting, quicksort, vba

I am using the code at the bottom to sort a column alphabetically, numerically and by the following alphabetical and punctuation characters (AB00017C).  Life is good on the single column sheet I am working on.  As long as data is in Column A everything looks great.

When I move to a sheet with more than one column, it's just plain ugly!

It's taken me two days to get this sort to work.  It inserts 3 helper columns to the right of column A, slices the cell values from column A into the three new columns and then sorts them in correct order.  At the end it deletes the 3 helper columns.

I have attached the code to a simple command button for testing.  I'm sorry that all the comments have been cut out by the forum.

I have sheets that go out to column CG that this subroutine would be very helpful on.

Now my head hurts, I think I have programmed myself into a corner and I don't know how to get out.

Any insights would be warmly welcomed, CraigMc

Below is some data

---

```
sku         post_title
AB00017a    Lixit, Glass Water Bottle, 32 oz.
AB00017     Lixit, Glass Water Bottle, 16 oz.
AB00016z    Hookbill Legume Blend with Peantus, 32 lbs.
AB00016-b   Bonito Loco Pretty Crazy Nut Blend, 32 lbs. 
AB00016     Madagascar Delite, 64 oz.
AB00017c    Nutmeats and Fruit, 32 lbs. 
AB00017g    Nutmeats and Fruit, 25 oz.
```

---

Here is the code:

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim intLoops    As Integer

    Dim lngNumeric  As Long
    Dim lngLastRow  As Long

    Dim rngRows     As Range
    Dim rngcell     As Range

    Dim strAlpha    As String
    Dim strPrefix   As String

    Dim strSuffix As String

    '-----------------------------
    strPrefix = "True"

    strSuffix = "False"
    '-----------------------------

    Columns("B:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight                                      'Insert 3 temporary columns to the Right of Column A.

    lngLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, Left("A1", 1)).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngRows = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))                'Separates Alpha to Next Column, Numeric to the following column
        For Each rngcell In rngRows
            intLoops = Len(rngcell)                                                 'Works on one character at at time.

                For intLoops = 1 To intLoops                                    'Read each character in the cell

                    If strPrefix = "True" Then

                        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(rngcell, intLoops, 1)) Then            'This is the PREFIX

                            strAlpha = strAlpha & Mid(rngcell, intLoops, 1)

                            If IsNumeric(Mid(rngcell, intLoops + 1, 1)) Then        'Is the next character Aphabetic, Yes this is the SUFFIX coming up.

                                strPrefix = "False"                             'Next Charater is the Suffix
                            End If

                        Else
                            lngNumeric = lngNumeric & Mid(rngcell, intLoops, 1)                   'No it is the number in the middle

                         End If

                    Else                                                        'This is the Suffix

                        If IsNumeric(Mid(rngcell, intLoops, 1)) And strSuffix = "False" Then

                            lngNumeric = lngNumeric & Mid(rngcell, intLoops, 1)                   'No it is the number in the middle

                            If (Mid(rngcell, intLoops + 1, 1)) = "-" Then           'Onceyou hit a non-numeric character stay in the suffix.

                                strSuffix = "True"                              'Ensures that all that follows the center number stays in the Suffix.

                            End If

                        Else

                            alpSuffix = alpSuffix & Mid(rngcell, intLoops, 1)       'Character SUFFIX

                        End If

                    End If

                Next intLoops

            rngcell.Offset(, 1) = strAlpha
            rngcell.Offset(, 2) = lngNumeric
            rngcell.Offset(, 3) = alpSuffix & " "
            strAlpha = vbNullString
            lngNumeric = 0
            alpSuffix = vbNullString
            strPrefix = "True"
            strSuffix = "False"
        Next rngcell
    Set rngRows = rngRows.Resize(rngRows.Rows.Count, 4)

    rngRows.Sort key1:=rngRows.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(rngRows.Rows.Count, 3)), order1:=xlAscending, _
                 key2:=rngRows.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(rngRows.Rows.Count, 2)), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess

    lngLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, Left("A2", 1)).End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Range("B1"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Range("C1"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Range("D1"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending

    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Header = xlYes
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Columns("B:D").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft                                       'Delete the 3 temporary columns to the Right of Column A.

End Sub
```

THANKS!

Comment: I am not clear on what you need help with. Are you trying to sort every column individually and independently or do you want to remove the restriction of having to work with column "A"?

Comment: You've worked hard to make this work, and explained the sorting well, but it would be helpful to have more details about the pattern for splitting - there might be easier (and faster) ways to do it. Related to what I think you're asking: the main issue is that you hard-coded the helper columns (B:D) so sheets already containing more columns of data will be shifted by your helper columns - the sorting ranges may not match properly. One way to overcome this is to dynamically find last column with data (similar to finding the last row with data) and place your helper columns beyond present data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes to fix the range issue, but the parsing of the strings worked well

My changes:

- I moved the main procedure to a new module
- I changed it to sort sheet "Master of Masters" specifically
- Renamed most of your variables to be a bit more intuitive
- Reduce interaction with the sheet objects by

  - copying data to memory, once
  - parsing the strings using your algorithm

    - but splitting strings is done in memory, not cells and ranges - improves performance
  - placing the data from memory back to the sheet, once
- Applying the sort to all data on the sheet (your sort area was not setup well)
- Remove the temporary helper columns

.

Here is the updated code, please place it in a new module

---

```
Option Explicit

'Place the code in a new module (from the menu: Insert -> Module)

Private Const START_COL As Byte = 1

Public Sub SortSheet(ByVal wsName As String, _
                     Optional ByVal sortCol As Long = 1, _
                     Optional ByVal row1 As Long = 2)

    Dim wb          As Workbook:    Dim ws          As Worksheet

    Dim lRow        As Long:        Dim lCol        As Long
    Dim thisRow     As Long:        Dim thisStr     As String
    Dim lastCell    As Range

    Dim sortRng     As Range:       Dim sortKey1    As Range
    Dim sortKey2    As Range:       Dim sortKey3    As Range

    Dim memArr1Col  As Variant      'column with strings         (in memory)
    Dim memArr3Col  As Variant      'helper columns, for sorting (in memory)

    Dim char        As Long:        Dim strLen      As Long
    Dim preBol      As Boolean:     Dim sufBol      As Boolean
    Dim midNum      As String
    Dim preStr      As String:      Dim sufStr      As String

    '---------------------------------------
    preBol = True
    sufBol = False
    '---------------------------------------
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wb = .ActiveWorkbook
    End With

    Set ws = Sheets(wsName)
    Set lastCell = GetMaxCell(ws.UsedRange)
    lRow = lastCell.Row
    lCol = lastCell.Column

    If row1 <= lRow Then

        With ws                             'set mem arrays: sort col, and helpers
            memArr1Col = .Range(.Cells(row1, sortCol), .Cells(lRow, sortCol))
            memArr3Col = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 3))
        End With

        For thisRow = row1 - 1 To lRow - 1  'parse each cell in sort column

            If Not IsEmpty(memArr1Col(thisRow, 1)) And _
               Not IsNull(memArr1Col(thisRow, 1)) And _
               Len(memArr1Col(thisRow, 1)) > 0 Then

                thisStr = memArr1Col(thisRow, 1)
                strLen = Len(thisStr)

                For char = 1 To strLen          'parse each string
                    If preBol = True Then
                        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(thisStr, char, 1)) Then
                            preStr = preStr & Mid(thisStr, char, 1)
                            preBol = Not IsNumeric(Mid(thisStr, char + 1, 1))
                        Else
                            midNum = midNum & Mid(thisStr, char, 1)
                        End If
                    Else
                        If IsNumeric(Mid(thisStr, char, 1)) And sufBol = False Then
                            midNum = midNum & Mid(thisStr, char, 1)
                            sufBol = (Mid(thisStr, char + 1, 1)) = "-"
                        Else
                            sufStr = sufStr & Mid(thisStr, char, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next   'Next character in the string
                memArr3Col(thisRow, 1) = preStr
                memArr3Col(thisRow, 2) = midNum
                memArr3Col(thisRow, 3) = sufStr & " "
                preBol = True
                sufBol = False
                midNum = vbNullString
                preStr = vbNullString
                sufStr = vbNullString
            End If
        Next   'Next Row

        With ws
            'place helper column values from memory to current worksheet
            .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 3)) = memArr3Col
            'set sort range - all data on this sheet plus the last 3 helper columns
            Set sortRng = .Range(.Cells(row1, START_COL), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 3))

            'set sort keys to helper columns
            Set sortKey1 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 1))
            Set sortKey2 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 2), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 2))
            Set sortKey3 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 3), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 3))
        End With

        With ws
            With .Sort  'apply the sort
                With .SortFields
                    .Clear
                    .Add sortKey1, xlSortOnValues, xlAscending
                    .Add sortKey2, xlSortOnValues, xlAscending
                    .Add sortKey3, xlSortOnValues, xlAscending
                End With
                .SetRange sortRng
                .Header = xlYes
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .Apply
            End With
            .Range( _
                    .Cells(row1, lCol + 1), _
                    .Cells(lRow, lCol + 3)).EntireColumn.Delete 'delete helper cols
            .Activate
            .Cells(1, 1).Activate
        End With
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

.

Place this function in the same (new) module

---

```
Public Function GetMaxCell(Optional ByRef rng As Range = Nothing) As Range

    'Returns the last cell of range with data, or A1 if Worksheet is empty

    Const NONEMPTY As String = "*"
    Dim lRow As Range, lCol As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        Set GetMaxCell = rng.Parent.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        With rng
            Set lRow = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                   After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            If Not lRow Is Nothing Then
                Set lCol = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                       After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                       SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

                Set GetMaxCell = .Parent.Cells(lRow.Row, lCol.Column)
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

---

.

You can call the main function from any Sheet module, like this:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    SortSheet wsName:="Master of Masters"

End Sub
```

---

or like this (to overwrite the default parameters)

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    SortSheet wsName:="Master of Masters", sortCol:=1, row1:=2

End Sub
```

---

.

To change the sort key modify the following 3 lines accordingly:

This sorts on **PreFix** (1st helper column, then 2nd, then 3rd):

```
Set sortKey1 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 1))   'PreFix: "AB"
Set sortKey2 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 2), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 2))   'Middle ID
Set sortKey3 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 3), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 3))   'PostFix
```

To sort on **Middle ID** Number (2nd helper column, then 1st, then 3rd):

```
Set sortKey1 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 2), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 2))   'Middle ID
Set sortKey2 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 1))   'PreFix: "AB"
Set sortKey3 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 3), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 3))   'PostFix
```

To sort on **PostFix** (3rd helper column, then 2nd, then 3rd):

```
Set sortKey1 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 3), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 3))   'PostFix
Set sortKey2 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 2), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 2))   'Middle ID
Set sortKey3 = .Range(.Cells(row1, lCol + 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 1))   'PreFix: "AB"
```

.

I tested it with data you provided. Here are the results:

.

[image: Before and After Sort]

.

**During sort** - illustrates the result of parsing the strings in the 3 helper columns

[image: During Sort]

Comment: Let me be clear about what I am trying to do.  This subroutine sorts one column on a worksheet.  When it sorts that column it sorts only the column not the row.  When the column is sorted it becomes out of sync with the rest of the row.  Some of my sheets have 64 columns.  This sub breaks down column A into three parts; 1. the alphabetic prefix. 2. the numeric center, and 3. the alphabetic suffix.  It then sorts the items into the correct sort order, that is 20 sorts before 1000.  I need to keep all of the rows data together.  It does me no go to associate the sku with the wrong product.Thanks

Comment: This subroutine also sorts 20 before 20a.  It does this by adding a space at the end of the line:  memArr3Col(thisRow, 3) = sufStr & " " to correct the sort order.  When the sort is done I will need to TRIM that space off.  It really meets my needs with the exception that it only sorts one column not the entire row or up to 64 columns.

Comment: How does it sort.  It loops through each character in the cell.  In the beginning all alphabetic characters go to column B.  When the next character to be tested IsNumeric(Mid(rngcell, intLoops + 1, 1)) is a number I set the strPrefix = "False", we no longer add anything to column B.  Then we loop through the numbers adding them to column C.  We look at the next character to be tested IF it is not a number or a "-" I set strSuffix = "True"  and we no longer add anything to column C.  The rest of the characters go to column D: alpSuffix = alpSuffix & Mid(rngcell, intLoops, 1).

Comment: When I write the suffix data to column D I add a space at the end to force the correct sort order where 20 comes before 20A.  Then I set the initial conditions: strAlpha = vbNullString, lngNumeric = 0, alpSuffix = vbNullString, strPrefix = "True", strSuffix = "False" and move to the next row down, Cell(i, 1) and start breaking the contents down into prefix, numeric, and suffix.  During the sort I respect the header in column A1 and leave it at the top of the row.  I just need to figure out how to sort the entire row, from column A to column CG.  Thanks for your help, I don't know how to fix it

Comment: When I updated the code I understood that you wanted to sort on three sections of the string "AB00017C": 1 "AB", 2 "00017", 3 whatever comes after the first 2 sections. What I'm not sure about is if you were deliberate about concatenating the bottle weight to the number. I'll updated my answer to illustrate how the parsing is performed and show you what I mean

Comment: The helper columns I add are of no consequence to the final result.  They are needed for the sort only.  I am thinking I need to select all the rows before I sort, with the helper columns in place.  Then at the end I just delete those helper columns.  I fully intend to pass in the sheet and row to be sorted once I figure out how to sort the entire sheet.  I am even willing to invoke an SQL for the sort for speed it that works, but I have not explored that option yet.  I am just unclear how to move all of the columns associated with column A when I sort.  I can't get my mind around it just yet.

Comment: I updated my answer to include an image showing exactly how the strings are parsed and how the sorting is applied. Try to run the code in my answer to see if it solves the problem of sorting the entire rows on the sheet or not, and if it does I can explain any details you may need

Comment: SortAllSheets eror: Type Mismatch:  on thisStr = memArr1Col(thisRow, 1).  SortAllSheets sortCol:=2, row1:=2 gives the same: Type Mismatch.  I am running your code on a sheet with 8 columns.  What I can see happening on the sheet before the Mismatch is out of order.

Comment: Can you tell me the value of "memArr1Col(thisRow, 1)" when the error occurs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81724/discussion-between-craigm-and-paul-bica).